# Replace the expression in unix

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I want to replace this expression

```
$$abc=select * from HR where hrid ='134-998-975'
```

to

```
$$abc=select * from HR where hrid <>'234-678-975'
```

I am using below command but it is not working

```
sed -i 's/$$abc=select * from HR where hrid <>'234-678-975'/$$abc=select * from HR where hrid <>'234-678-975'/g' my location/abc.parm
```

Answer (score 0):

If **all** occurrences of your *"="* (equal sign) you want to replace have *" ' "* (single quotation mark) after, you can just simply use (to see the output in console):

```sh
sed "s/='/<>'/g" your_file.ext
```

if you want the output to be saved in the same file, use:

```sh
sed -i "s/='/<>'/g" your_file.ext
```

if you want the output to be saved in the new file, use:

```sh
sed "s/='/<>'/g" your_file.ext > newfile.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the output/error that you get after you run this command. I don't think sed would parse the command if you run it as you posted.

```
root@root:~# echo "arun = kumar = arun kumar" | sed 's/=/<>/2' 
arun = kumar <> arun kumar
```

If you would like to replace the second occurrence, you can do it by specifying `2` instead of `g` for the substitute(s) command.

Comment: I didn't get any error but my expected changes doesn't perform

Comment: If i used this it works.                                       sed -i 's/$$abc=N/$$abc=Y/g' mylocation/abc.parm

Comment: $ means end-of-line, i think you need to escape it. And 'g' means global, you have to use '2'. Also please escape single-quote too.